# Table partitioning in PostgreSQL 11 with automatic partition creation?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, partitioning

I need to maintain audit table and since the number of changes are going to be huge, I need an efficient way of dealing with the problem. The solution which I have thought is to record only the changed column in the audit table and partition it on the `createdon` column quarterly or half-yearly.

I wanted to know if there is anything like 'interval partition' of oracle? If not then how can I achieve it?

**I want that every 6 months a new partition is created automatically as the row is inserted.**

I am using postgres 11 as my db.

Comment: You can't - there is no "automatic partition creation" in Postgres. Not in 11 nor in the upcoming 12. You need something like https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman for that. But why not simply have a cron job that runs every 6 months and creates the partitions for the next 6 months?

Comment: yeah I will do that only if there's no other way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is it impossible with a trigger? (genuine question, I need to achieve the same thing than OP). My table is partitioned per week based on a column `timestamp`.

Comment: @GG. - Partitioned tables cannot have BEFORE / FOR EACH ROW triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any magic configuration that make your life easier on this point :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html

If you want the table auto-created, I think you have two major possibilities :

- Verify each data at the in of the 'mother' table to see if it fits in an already present partition (trigger, if huge amount of inserts it could be a problem)
- Check once in a while that you already have the partitions that are going to be needed in the future. For this one pg_partman is going to be your best ally.

As an example, few years ago, I had done a partition mechanism when there was only the declarative one and not any possibility to add pg_partman. With the trigger mechanism for 15 million rows per month it still works like a charm.

If you do not want to harm your performances EVER (and especially if you do not know how large your system is going to grow) I recommand to you the same response than in a_horse_with_no_name comment : use pg_partman.

If you cannot use it, like it was the case for me, adopt one of the two philosophies (trigger or advance table creation by crontask (for example)).

Comment: Why using a windows licence for a postgresql server? Can't you just roll over with a Linux distribution?

Comment: because sometimes they just can't.